# In which package can I find Xamarin IDevice

Tags: xamarin

I am writing a Xamarin Forms PCL application (both iOS and Android)

I have to pick an image from phone gallery.

I have read some documentation about this plugin:

```
Labs.Platform.Services.Media.MediaPicker
```

In my Common project, i have to put this code:

```
   var device = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();
   picker = DependencyService.Get<IMediaPicker>() ?? device.MediaPicker;
```

But I have an error on the first line: IDevice and Resolver Objects are not know. I think I am missing a reference or a using clause.

Thanks

Comment: You think you are missing a using/reference.. So, do you have a using/reference/import for `IDevice` for example? Please also provide this code's context and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As minimal example, you just have to create an empty project in xamarin and paste the 2 lines. I have tried a lot of using/reference but none works...

Comment: @Bob5421 your *minimal example* does not have you adding the Nuget/package and adding a `using XLabs.Platform.Device` clause....

Comment: You probably miss the NuGet package, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the following Nuget package in all of your projects in the solution (i.e. PCL core project, iOS project, and the Android Project, and UWP project if using it):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.Forms/

And you will need to add the following `using` statements:

```
using XLabs.Ioc;
using XLabs.Platform.Device;
using XLabs.Platform.Services.Media;
```